# UI not updating after updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am Passing a function from Parent component to child component and then calling that function in child component to update the state of parent component.

**In Parent component:**

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const updateTodoInUiAfterEdit = (updatedTodo, todoIdOfEdited)=>{
        var temp = todos;
        for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i].todo_id === todoIdOfEdited){
                temp[i].description = updatedTodo;
                break;
            }
        }
        setTodos(temp);
        console.log(todos);
}
```

**It is logging the updated state here correctly, but UI is not updating as per latest state**

Comment: Share the full code that can be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are directly changing the state, which is wrong.

**Do not mutate the state directly**

See the updated code:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const updateTodoInUiAfterEdit = (updatedTodo, todoIdOfEdited)=>{
        //making a copy of todos up to one depth, if you have more than 
        //one depth, then you have to deep clone it
        const temp = [...todos];
        for(let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i].todo_id === todoIdOfEdited){
                temp[i].description = updatedTodo;
                break;
            }
        }
        setTodos(temp);
        console.log(todos);
}
```

PS: Use let/const instead of var.

Comment: In question, temp is having shallow copy of todos. So, when we make any change  in temp, it also updates the todo, but UI won't rerender as we have not changed todos using Setter. And when we use setter(setTodos(temp)), it won't rerender as temp and todos are already same.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const updateTodoInUiAfterEdit = (updatedTodo, todoIdOfEdited)=>{
        let temp = todos;
        let newTodo = []
        for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i].todo_id === todoIdOfEdited){
                temp[i].description = updatedTodo;
            }
            newTodo.push(temp[i]);
        }
        setTodos(newTodo);
        console.log(todos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTodos` is an asynchronous function, which means that the state updates will not take effect immediately.

For tackling it you have to update the setTodo by using its previous state as an argument.

Here's helping code:

```
const updateTodoInUiAfterEdit = (updatedTodo, todoIdOfEdited) => {
  setTodos(prevTodos => {
    const temp = [...prevTodos];
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      if (temp[i].todo_id === todoIdOfEdited) {
        temp[i].description = updatedTodo;
        break;
      }
    }
    return temp;
  });
};
```

Upvote if it helps..  :)

Comment: This code works, but explanation is not correct.